# Changes in default behavior in OpenIdConnectOptions between .Net Framework and .Net Core versions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, single-sign-on, openid-connect, middleware

In OpenIdConnect middleware we have an option UseTokenLifetime from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectoptions.usetokenlifetime?view=aspnetcore-7.0) this property is use for:

> Indicates that the authentication session lifetime (e.g. cookies)
> should match that of the authentication token. If the token does not
> provide lifetime information then normal session lifetimes will be
> used.

In .Net Framework this property have the default value **true**, but since .Net Core the default behavior was changed and now the default value in **false**.

I have the following questions:

- What the motivation behind this changes
- What the best practices
- What recommendation from the OpenID Connect Standard regarding this.

Thanks for advance

Comment: For this kind of question about the underlying design, I recommend you to ask questions in [github issues](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues). Microsoft PG will generally review the above issues, and it may take some time.